# Getting unmatched ". on a simple csh ssh script

Tags: linux, ssh, foreach, csh

I'm trying to connect to a set of machines using foreach to check whether or not a file exists, however I keep getting the unmatched " error, I've tried plenty of ways and plenty of escape character to try to make it work... however I still get the error, here is the code:

```
foreach i ( machineA machineB machineC machineD machineE )
foreach? echo $i":"
foreach? ssh -q $i "\[ -f /etc/init.d/myprog \] \&\& echo \"File exists\" \|\| echo \"File does not exist\""
foreach? end
machineA:
Unmatched ".
```

Probably something silly, but I've been trying to make it work over the last couple of hours with no success...

The line I'm trying to execute remotely through ssh is this:

```
[ -f /etc/init.d/myprog ] && echo "File exists" || echo "File does not exist"
```

And also tried this way (amongst several other ways):

```
foreach? ssh -q -o "BatchMode=yes" $i "[ -f /etc/init.d/netbatch ]" && echo \"File exists\" \|\| echo \"File does not exists\""
```

Thanks a lot for any help!!!

Comment: This is `csh` code, not `bash` code; I've edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, quoting is csh has always been a bit dodgy.

Try this:

```
foreach i ( machineA machineB machineC machineD machineE )
echo $i":"
ssh -q $i '[ -f /etc/init.d/myprog ] && echo "File exists" || echo "File does not exist"'
end
```

Nothing is expanded in single quotes which eliminates the need to escape everything.